# Unable to export to Excel in IE 8

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer-8, export-to-excel

i am unable to export to excel in IE 8. i keep getting the following: 
"IE cannot download filename.aspx from url."
"IE was not able to open this internet site. t he requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. pelse try again"

looks to me like it's itgnoring the https, and trying to open http, but i could be wrong.
per this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308

my code is:

```
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                gvResources.RenderControl(htw);

                Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders()
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=AdHocReport.xls");
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.End();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export to Excel doesnt work on IE under SSL (https)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672073/export-to-excel-doesnt-work-on-ie-under-ssl-https)

Comment: thank you! it's very similar, but i'm not doing it exacly the same, and the line of code that was causing error in the other post - i dont have ;( i wish it was that easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the IIS application pool. resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I found a lead that suggests you need to disable cache control headers.

Give this a shot:

```
 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Source: [Random Forum Conversation](http://download.hkvstore.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=15477) | [Another Possible Lead](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-setCacheable-false-No-Cache-Header-in-WebResource-td3765955.html)

Also: [SetCacheability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setcacheability(v=vs.71).aspx)

...I was hoping to uncover some deeper understanding, but that's all I found.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the space in your content disposition, also try adding quotes around the filename:

```
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"AdHocReport.xls\"");
```

Is there a reason you are using a string writer with write instead of a stream with binarywrite?

Comment: i didn't write the code originally, just trying to figure out why the export is not working. unfortunately modified the header as you suggested did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I just was able to fix this issue. I added the following lines after `response.clear()`...

```
    Response.ClearHeaders()
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache ")
```